# Can I have two public classes in spring - boot?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

In my springboot application I am needing to deploy to an existing tomcat server so I need to deploy the application as a war file.   In order to do that I have to alter my main class a bit.

I currently have the following code in my main application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private UserService userservice;

public Static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

I need to change it to the following to be able to have maven change it to a war file instead of a jar.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Problem is I need the commandlinerunner implemented as well.  Can I have both?  If so how would I go about doing this?  I have searched and the information I have found so far has been ambiguous at best.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as well as the documentation so I can review it as well as share it if I come across others having a similar issue.

EDIT:  I did find one document that seemed to imply I could have both implimented within the same application.java and within the pom.xml file stating which one should be initialized first.  Would this be a correct way of doing this?  I read in another overstack that an individual that tried this ended up with two applications because of it.  Unfortunately he did not provide much code to explain what he tried, only what his outcome was.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.